# how to make scroll bar(even inactive) disappear using jquery

Tags: jquery

i want that when a div increase than a height i have set, then only it should show scroll bar, otherwise the inactive scrollbar should also not be shown.

i am using the following code for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($('.dialog-text').height()<=119 ){
    $(this).css('overflow-y', "hidden");


    }
    else{
    $(this).css('overflow-y', "scroll");
    }
});
```

obviously i must have done something wrong. please point it out or give a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `auto` value of [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y).

Remove the JS you've added, and add this style to the CSS:

```
.dialog-text
{
    height: 119px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

---

**auto value for overflow**

> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers like Firefox provide
>   scrollbars if content overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only runs once, when your site loads. If your div changes content after loading then you need make a function to check the height and modify it if needed immediately after changing the content of the div, or use something like [attrchange](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/) to listen to the height changes of the div, and hide the scrollbar if necessary.